# Registering a user through Rails API and returning validation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, jbuilder

I'm trying to build a controller action which will create a new user in my application. I want it to attempt to create the user and if it succeeds, return the `User` model and if it fails show the validation errors. So far I've got this mostly up and running:

```
# app/controllers/v1/users_controller.rb

def create
  @user = User.create(user_params)
end

private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password) if params[:user]
  end
```

and I'm using JBuilder in my view like so:

```
# app/views/v1/users/create.json.jbuilder

if @user.errors
  json.errors @user.errors
else
  json.user @user
end
```

This looks like it'd work to me, however when I create a new user that doesn't have any validation errors I get this output rather than the `User` that just got created:

```
{"errors":{}}
```

How come it's printing out the empty errors when the user has no validation errors?

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, only *nil* and *false* evaluate to false in the *if* statement. In your example above, @user.errors is an ActiveModel::Errors class and therefore evaluate to true. Try changing the code above to:

```
if @user.errors.present?
  json.errors @user.errors
else
  json.user @user
end
```